# NSPredicateEditor does not resize NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nspredicateeditor

Is there a workable way to make `NSPredicateEditor` resize `NSTextField`?

All I got is to subclass `NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate` and write in my class the following function:

```
- (void)setTextFieldFrameWithPredicateEditor:(NSPredicateEditor *)predicateEditor{
    NSArray *arr = [self templateViews];
    NSView *view = [arr lastObject];
    NSSize needSize = NSMakeSize(NSMaxX(predicateEditor.frame), 17);
    [view setFrameSize:needSize];
}
```

There is no effect from setting anchors(margins) by `[view setAutoresizingMask:(NSViewMaxXMargin | NSViewWidthSizable)]`

I call this function every time the show NSPredicateEditor by pressing a button, and every time in function `-(IBAction)predicateEditorChanged:(NSPredicateEditor *)sender`. It seems working correctly, but when many times I change the settings NSPredicateEditor at some time resizing starts to work not correct.

Any help please.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to create a custom NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate and override the templateViews method.

Like this:

```
- (NSArray *)templateViews {
    NSArray *views = [super templateViews];
    NSView *lastView = [views lastObject];
    NSRect viewFrame = lastView.frame;
    viewFrame.size.width = 100.0f;
    lastView.frame = viewFrame;
    return views;
}
```

And then set the width to whatever you need it to be.